# How to dynamically check $rootScope.userDetails in AngularJS header template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have two different headers based on if a user is logged in or not. User Access details are stored in $rootScope.userDetails. The property is deleted from the $rootScope object as soon as I have logged out. The problem is my header file does not recognise the change in object and keeps showing the original header throughout the app.

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>


</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController" >


<div class="main">
    <!-- Render views -->
        <div class="sections">
            <section ng-show="angular.isDefined(userDetails)">
                <!-- Second Header -->
```

I have also tried {{userDetails !== undefined}} to no avail. console.log($rootScope.userDetails) tells me that the object property is being deleted and added approprately as I login and logout. I suspect that the header/footer code is treated as static by AngularJS and ng-view dynamically adds data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular.isDefined(userDetails)` will not work in your views, because `angular` object is not in your scope. You can try `ng-show="userDetails !== undefined"`.